# how to display all posts in wordpress with single post style

Tags: php, wordpress, post

this may be a really basic question but im after displaying all my posts on my homepage in order of being published. this was initially like this, but i've fiddled round with the hompage for something completely different! i still want that homepage but for all my posts to reside under it

any help would be really appreciated

my current index page is as follows -

```
<?php include "header.php"; ?>


<div id="wrapper">



<?php include "iframe.php"; ?>

<?php include "sidebar.php"; ?>



</div>
```

Comment: The code sample doesn't give enough info. I'm not familiar with Wordpress, but aren't you supposed to configure this in the admin area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress Codex suggests the following

```
<?php
$allposts = get_posts( array('numberposts' => -1) );
foreach($allposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>  
    <?php the_content();
endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: i just get syntax error. do i put something in with this?

Comment: That code needs to be wrapped in the PHP brackets of course. I've added them into the code to clarify.